# Is there a way to alter the current user's password introducing a variable for the password?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a procedure that allows a Java application change password to the user that is logged on. 
However, the statement "ALTER USER user() IDENTIFIED BY " doesnt allow me to insert a variable as the new password.
Is there any way I can do this?

I've tried using the procedure's argument, declaring new variables and using different types, such as BLOB or VARCHAR.

```
 create procedure change_password 
 (
 in new_password BLOB
 ) 
 begin
    SET @col = new_password;
    ALTER USER user() IDENTIFIED BY @col;
 */end#
 delimiter ;
```

I expect "alter user" taking a variable as an argument for the new password but it's a syntax error, since it just allow text through quotation marks

Comment: `the user` is a database user or application user? Probably you are looking for an `update`.

Comment: Database user, although @nbk solution works almost perfectly. Problem is it only changes root password even if I log on with another user

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `change_password`(in new_password text)
BEGIN 
  SET @textnew  =  CONCAT("ALTER USER user() IDENTIFIED BY '",new_password,"';");
  PREPARE stmt FROM @textnew;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

So that for mysql you have an actual String in position of the password.

But there are a lot of restrictions, like the user have to have privileges.

See also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-user.html

Comment: It works, but somehow it only changes root password, even if I'm logged with another user.

Comment: You see the first line, there stands DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` remove it. I updated ,my answer.

Comment: I thought it could be that, but DEFINER is setted by default by the workbench. When I try to execute that statement without `DEFINER=root@localhost` and I go to check it through the alter procedure tool of the workbench, it is again setted.